# Finding the linear transformation given certain conditions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> A certain linear transformation diagonalizes with respect to the base $\mathcal{B}=\{(1,2,2),(-3,-2,-1),(1,1,1)\}$, and the vector $(-1,2,-3)$ is mapped to the vector $(-25,-22,-27)$. Find the representation of the transformation $T$ with respect to the canonical base $\mathcal{C}=\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$.
>
> **Answer:**
> $$T=\begin{pmatrix}3 && -5 && 4 \\ 2 && -4 && 4 \\ 2 && -5 && 5\end{pmatrix}$$

So I tried to solve this problem and this is what I've come up with. I know that, $$P=\begin{pmatrix}1 && -3 && 1 \\ 2 && -2 && 1 \\ 2 && -1 && 1\end{pmatrix}$$ and so my linear transformation $T$ obeys the following $$D=P^{-1}TP$$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix and $T$ is the transformation they are asking for. I know that there are much more general answers like this in this forum but I don't seem to grasp the meaning behind any of them. Can anyone one enlighten me or help me with this precise example? Thanks!

Comment: @downvoter: why the down vote? I think the question is perfectly presented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have$$(-1,2,-3)=8(1,2,2)-5(-3,-2,-1)-24(1,1,1).$$Therefore, if $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$ are the eigenvalues corresponding to $(1,2,2)$, $(-3,-2,-1)$, and $(1,1,1)$ respectively. Then\begin{align}(−25,−22,−27)&=T(-1,2,-3)\\&=T\bigl(8(1,2,2)-5(-3,-2,-1)-24(1,1,1)\bigr)\\&=8\alpha(1,2,2)-5\beta(-3,-2,-1)-24\gamma(1,1,1)\end{align}and$$(−25,−22,−27)=8\alpha(1,2,2)-5\beta(-3,-2,-1)-24\gamma(1,1,1)\iff(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)=(1,1,2).$$So, you know that the matrix of $T$ with respect to the basis $\{(1,2,2),(-3,-2,-1),(1,1,1)\}$ is$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&2\end{bmatrix}.$$Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you. Now, since you have found the diagonal matrix $D$ i can now compute the matrix product to find the linear tranformation $T$ like $$PDP^{-1}=T$$

Comment: Also, I guess that you are saying that $T(8(1,2,2)-5(-3,-2,-1)-24(1,1,1))=8\alpha (1,2,2)-5\beta (-3,-2,-1)-24\gamma (1,1,1)$ because $T$ is a linear map, and so $T(\alpha a+b)=\alpha T(a+b)$ right? I don't really understand why do you write the vector $(-1,2,-3)$ with respect to the base $\mathcal{B}$ of eigenvectors. Is it part of the method/proceeding?

Comment: Actually, $T$ being a linear map means that $T(\alpha a+b)=\alpha T(a)+T(b)$. And I know nothing about a method/proceedings. I found a solution and I wrote it.